# Why does text-overflow:ellipsis not work here:

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use the structure below, but the ellipses don't show. What's wrong?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYSBA/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>One two three four five six seven</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {height:30px; overflow:hidden; background:#eee;}
ul {float:left; margin:0; padding:0;}
li
{
    float:left;
    height:28px; margin-left:4px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    font: 10px/28px Arial; color:#333;
    padding:0 4px;
    width:100px;
    text-overflow:-moz-ellipsis;
    text-overflow:-webkit-ellipsis;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ellipsis to work `overflow:hidden` needs to be applied to THAT element together with `white-space: nowrap;`

```
li {
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/jbDWL/)

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you.